# Auto seleccionar un option del select con Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Quisiera que se autoseleccionara el primer valor de un `select`.

Como verán, mi código es el siguiente. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal:

**El HTML:**

```
<div class="row" style="display:block; margin-top:-95px" ng-controller="lista_claves">
    <center>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box  box-solid collapsed-box " id="oficinas" ng-repeat="item in claves">

                <div  class="box-header" data-widget="collapse" >

                    <img class="lupa" src="css/galeria/zoom.png" style="float:left; width:14px;height:18px; margin-left:2%;margin-top: 3%;" />

                    <h2 class="box-title" display="block" style="float:left; margin-left:2%;"> {{item.documentos}} </h2>
                    <img class="change" src="css/galeria/down.png" style="float:right; width:7%;margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 4%;" />
                   
                    <p id="typee" value="{{item.descripcion}}"></p>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body" id="uniq" ng-controller="detalle_referenciacontrol">
                    <!--aqui estaba el filtro
                        
                        --><select id="set" name="show-filter" ng-model="searchinput" >
                        <option id="plunkr" selected="selected" value="{{item.descripcion}}"></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="twit" ng-model="searchinput" readonly  value="{{item.descripcion}}" placeholder="{{item.descripcion}}" cloack />                     
                    <center>
                       
                        <table class="table table-hover" style="margin:auto">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="item in itemsarchivo | filter:{tipodescrip:searchinput}" id="{{item.path}}" onclick="ver(this)">
                                    <td><b style="float:left;">{{item.nombre}}</b><img src="css/galeria/doc.png" style="float:right"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

**El código con el que trato de autoseleccionar:**

```
<script>
      $(document).ready  (
      function dialog_submit(val) {
          document.getElementById('twit').value = val;

          $("#uniq select").each(function () {
                                      
              $("#set").val = val;
               
          });
      }
      );
</script>
```

**Los elementos que cargo en el `select` son los siguientes:**

```
$scope.claves =  [
        {
            "documentos": "Sin clasificar (1)",
            "clave": "0",
            "descripcion": "Sin clasificar"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Pedimento Aduanal (3)",
            "clave": "2",
            "descripcion": "Pedimento Aduanal"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros) (4)",
            "clave": "3",
            "descripcion": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ (2)",
            "clave": "4",
            "descripcion": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "COVE (4)",
            "clave": "5",
            "descripcion": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias) (1)",
            "clave": "6",
            "descripcion": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte (1)",
            "clave": "25",
            "descripcion": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: ¿Probaste con? `$("#set")[0].selectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: Ya lo intente y no me funciono ):

Comment: @emanuelle que items estas cargando en el Select? veo que usas AngularJS

Comment: cargue arriba los items que cargo en mi select siempre se llena con uno y ese es el que quiero autoseleccionar

Comment: Una pregunta, tu select si alacanza a llenarse las opciones  opciones ?

Comment: @emanuelle Aun sigues teniendo problema? si ya lo solucionaste, cuentanos.

Comment: Hola ya quedo solucionado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una nueva variable y asignarle el primer `item` del `array` de `objetos`, también debes crear un nuevo `<option>` como lo ves a continuación, cualquier duda quedo pendiente.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.claves =  [
        {
            "documentos": "Sin clasificar (1)",
            "clave": "0",
            "descripcion": "Sin clasificar"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Pedimento Aduanal (3)",
            "clave": "2",
            "descripcion": "Pedimento Aduanal"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros) (4)",
            "clave": "3",
            "descripcion": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ (2)",
            "clave": "4",
            "descripcion": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "COVE (4)",
            "clave": "5",
            "descripcion": "COVE"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias) (1)",
            "clave": "6",
            "descripcion": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)"
        },
        {
            "documentos": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte (1)",
            "clave": "25",
            "descripcion": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
        }
    ]

    $scope.firstItem = $scope.claves[0];
    

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="set" name="show-filter" ng-model="searchinput">
        <option id="firstItem" ng-value="" selected ng-bind="firstItem.descripcion"></option>
        <option id="plunkr" ng-value="item.descripcion">Segundo Item</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="twit" ng-model="searchinput" readonly  value="{{item.descripcion}}" placeholder="{{item.descripcion}}" cloack />                     
    <center>

        <table class="table table-hover" style="margin:auto">
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in itemsarchivo | filter:{tipodescrip:searchinput}" id="{{item.path}}" onclick="ver(this)">
                    <td><b style="float:left;">{{item.nombre}}</b><img src="css/galeria/doc.png" style="float:right"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! se me dificulta un poco ya que como hay un ng-repeat el siguiente select tendria que llebar  $scope.firstItem = $scope.claves[2]; y el tercer select $scope.firstItem = $scope.claves[3];
y estos datos del array son dinamicos me llegan como respuesta aun request post alguna sugerencia @theVicius

Comment: @emanuelle entonces edita un poco tu código  y coloca el ng-repeat que va antes del select. Agrega mas codigo.

Comment: ya lo edite esque es un bloque grande y queria sintetizar un poco

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estas utilizando angular, puedes utilizar la directiva `ng-init` para asignarle un valor al modelo `searchinput`. En este caso, debe asignarle el object como se muestra en el ejemplo que te he adjuntado.

```
ng-init="searchinput = claves[0]"
```

Igualmente he agregado la directiva ng-options para poblar las opciones que se deben mostrar en el select.

```js
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);
app.controller('exampleController', function($scope) {

  $scope.claves =  [
          {
              "documentos": "Sin clasificar (1)",
              "clave": "0",
              "descripcion": "Sin clasificar"
          },
          {
              "documentos": "Pedimento Aduanal (3)",
              "clave": "2",
              "descripcion": "Pedimento Aduanal"
          },
          {
              "documentos": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros) (4)",
              "clave": "3",
              "descripcion": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)"
          },
          {
              "documentos": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ (2)",
              "clave": "4",
              "descripcion": "Cuentas de Gastos MOZ"
          },
          {
              "documentos": "COVE (4)",
              "clave": "5",
              "descripcion": "COVE"
          },
          {
              "documentos": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias) (1)",
              "clave": "6",
              "descripcion": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)"
          },
          {
              "documentos": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte (1)",
              "clave": "25",
              "descripcion": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
          }
      ];
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="exampleController">
  <select id="set" name="show-filter" ng-init="searchinput = claves[0]" ng-model="searchinput" ng-options="item as item.descripcion for item in claves track by item.clave">
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

La verdad no se entiende que es lo que quieres hacer en el javascript, de igual modo te voy a explicar como acceder a las opciones de un select cualquiera (que ya esté renderizado en pantalla).

suponiendo que este es mi select:

```
 <select id='myId'>
    <option> 1</option>
    <option> 2</option>
    <option> 3</option>
    <option> 4</option>
</select>
```

Las opciones son elementos hijos del select de tal modo que lo unico que hay que  hacer para seleccionar una opcion es setear el parametro selected a true en cualquiera de esas opciones así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function(){
        var select=document.getElementById('myId');
        select.children[0].selected=true;
        //select.options[0].selected=true;
       //cualquiera de las dos funciona tanto children como options
    }
</script>
```

Entonces para seleccionar automaticamente la primera opcion de tu  select solo se debe hacer:

```
     $(document).ready(()=>{
        var select=document.getElementById('#set');
        select.children[0].selected=true;
     });
```

---

De aca para abajo es algo que me parece puede estar afectando.

Como estas usando algun framework para dibujar las opciones, no se cual es (angular, vue, react...) puede que ningun script se ejecute como esperas sobre ese select por una razón y es que `$(document).ready` no nos acegura que el select ya tenga las opciones adentro. Si ese es el caso debe arrojar un error en consola...

Si lo anterior pasa hay muchas soluciones y una de ellas podria ser un setTimeout que le de suficiente tiempo al navegador para que renderice las opciones.

```
 $(document).ready(()=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            var select=document.getElementById('#set');
            select.children[0].selected=true;
         },1000);
     });
```

Puede que tu codigo este bien y sea por esto último (solo tendrias que poner el codigo dentro del setTimeout o un setInterval que valide si select ya tiene mas de una option). Lo puse en javascript puro porque en este caso  no se me hace necesario el uso de jquery.

Answer (score -1):

> La forma correcta que a mi me funcionó es bastante sencilla:
> Llamas al Select
> `var select=document.getElementById('#set');`
> Luego le asignas el valor que coincida con algunas de las opciones que tienes en el mismo Select. Ejemplo:
> `select.value = "~~Valor del Select~~";`

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).